# Ordenar alfabéticamente palabras que están almacenadas en una matriz C

Tags: c, dev-c++

Quiero saber si es posible ordenar las palabras de una matriz de doble puntero.
Que hay que hacer, que el usuario ingrese x palabras, las que el desee, pero debe existir una función que las ordene, por ejemplo:
**palabra 1 : "murciélago" el programa pide la letra al usuario de la que empezara a ordenar por ejemplo *"c"* y en la impresion de palabra debería salir -> cgilmrouae** y asi consecutivamente con todas las demas
Necesito que las palabras que ya estan guardadas me las ordene alfabeticamente comenzando desde una letra quue el usuario elija.
y así con todas las palabras que se guardaron en el doble apuntador.
Tengo todo lo demás solo me falta que se organice de esa manera...

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
/*PROTOTIPOS DE LAS FUNCIONES QUE SE UTILIZARAN EN EL PROGRAMA*/
void captura(char **, int, int[]);
void validaCadena(char [], char *);
void impresionDatos(char **, int, int[]);
void ordenar(char **, int, char **);

int main()
{
    
    char **pP;//DEclaracion de Arreglo de doble apuntador tipo char 
    char **palabras;
    int pal = 0, contador[20];
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de palabras que va a registrar->");
    scanf("%d", &pal);
    fflush(stdin);
    palabras = (char **)malloc(pal * sizeof(char*));
    pP = (char **)malloc(pal * sizeof(char*));//Asignacion de memoria dependiendo de cuantas palabras registrara el usuario
    captura(pP, pal, contador);//Llamada a la funcion mandando el arreglo mas la cantidad de registros y un arreglo tipo int para almacenar la cantidad de caracteres
    impresionDatos(pP, pal, contador);//Llamada a la funcion mandando el arreglo mas la cantidad de registros y un arreglo tipo int para almacenar la cantidad de caracteres para su impresion
    ordenar(pP, pal, palabras);
    impresionDatos(pP, pal, contador);
    free(pP); //Liberacion de memoria;
    return 0;
}

void ordenar(char **pP, int pal, char **palabras)
{
    char letra, *aux;
    bool bandera = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < pal; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", pP[i]);
        bandera = true;
        while(bandera)
        {
            printf("Ingrese la letra a buscar %d->", i);
            scanf("%c", &letra);
            fflush(stdin);
            for (int j = 0; j < strlen(pP[i]); j++)
            {
                if(pP[i][j] == letra){
                    printf("Encontrado");
                    
                    for(int x = 0; x < strlen(pP[i]); x++){
                        for(int y = 0; y<x; y++){
                            aux = pP[i];
                            pP[i] = pP[j];
                            pP[j] = aux;
                        }
                    }
                    bandera = false;
                }else{
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void impresionDatos2(char **palabras, int pal, int contador[])//Recibe todos los parametros especificando el tipo que le pertenece a cada uno
{
    system("cls");//Borrado de pantalla
    printf("PALABRA\t BYTES\t DIRECCION\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < pal; i++)//Ciclo for que se reoite desde 0 hasta la cantidad de registros introducida
    {
        printf("%s\t %d\t %d\n", palabras[i], contador[i], &palabras[i]);   //impresion de datos solicitados comenzando con la palabra almacenada en pP[indice]
                                                                //Despues imprimimos el contador que es donde se almacena la cantidad de caracteres de su respectiva palabra indicado tambien por contador[indice]
                                                                //al ultimo impresion de direccion de memoria de la palabra &pP[indice]
    }   
}

void impresionDatos(char **pP, int pal, int contador[])//Recibe todos los parametros especificando el tipo que le pertenece a cada uno
{
    system("cls");//Borrado de pantalla
    printf("PALABRA\t BYTES\t DIRECCION\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < pal; i++)//Ciclo for que se reoite desde 0 hasta la cantidad de registros introducida
    {
        printf("%s\t %d\t %d\n", pP[i], contador[i], &pP[i]);   //impresion de datos solicitados comenzando con la palabra almacenada en pP[indice]
                                                                //Despues imprimimos el contador que es donde se almacena la cantidad de caracteres de su respectiva palabra indicado tambien por contador[indice]
                                                                //al ultimo impresion de direccion de memoria de la palabra &pP[indice]
    }   
}

void captura(char **pP, int pal, int contador[])//Recibe todos los parametros especificando el tipo que le pertenece a cada uno
{
    char palabra[50];
    int sizeP = 0;
    bool bandera = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < pal; i++)
    {
        sizeP = 0;
        fflush(stdin);
        validaCadena(palabra, "Palabra->");//llamada a la funcion para validar que la palabra introducida no contenga la letra 'P' || 'p'
        for(int j  = 0; j <= strlen(palabra); j++){ //Strlen funcion para medir el tamaño de la cadena en este caso palabra
            sizeP += 1; //Variable que va sumando el total de caracteres de la cadena
        }
        contador[i] = sizeP; // el contador[indice] almacena el resultado final de nuestro "sumador de caracteres" sizeP
        pP[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeP * sizeof(char));//asignacion de memoria dependiendo de la canridad de caracteres de la palabra 
        for (int k = 0; k < sizeP; k++)
            {
                pP[i][k] = palabra[k]; //A cada posicion  de pP[i][k] se le va guardando cada letra indicada por palabra[indice]
            }
    }
}

void validaCadena(char palabra[],char *mensaje)//funcion que recible el arreglo tipo char y el mensaje que se encuentra en la llamada de la función
{
    
    char cadena[50] = "";
    bool bandera = true;
    int cont = 0;
    while (bandera)
    {
        printf("%s", mensaje);//Impresion del mensaje que viene desde la llamada de la funcion
        scanf("%[^\n]", cadena);//almacena la palabra que introduciremos 
        fflush(stdin);
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(cadena); i++)
        {
            if (cadena[i] == 'p' || cadena[i] == 'P')//Si el for a estar letra por letra encuentra una p o P mayus entra a la condicion y hace break solicitando nuevamente introducir una palabra
            {
                break;
            }
            if (i == (strlen(cadena) - 1))//Si nuestra i (indice) es igual a la cantidad de caracteres existentes en nuestra cadena
            {
            strcpy(palabra, cadena);//Con la funcion strcpy sustituimos el string(palabra en este caso) cadena por 
                                 //lo que traemos de valor en la variable nombre la cual es la que mandamos desde llamada
            bandera = false;//Cambiamos el valor de bandera bool a false para salir del while
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Este es el codigo que llevo hasta el momento, la función esta incompleta y no funciona

Comment: Porque el resultado es `caegilmrou`?? Si empece a ordenar a partir de la `c` no se supone que no debo tomar en cuenta los caracteres que esten antes de la `c`... Podrias dar otros ejemplos?

Comment: Si amigo! exactamente así como dijiste, ya corregí mi publicacion.

Comment: No entiendo cómo se pasa de **murciélago** a **cgilmrouae** (la **e** pierde el acento, la **a** no está al principio, la **o** no está antes de la **r**...).

Comment: Se ordena la palabra a partir de la letra que seleccione el usuario, en ese ejemplo eligio la "c" entonces se ordena de la c en adelante

Comment: Pero sigo sin entender, si se empieza a ordenar a partir de la `c`, entonces, porque tomas en cuenta la `m`? El resultado no deberia ser `cgilmrouae` sino, `acegilo`(aqui no tomo en cuenta la tilde de la `e`..). Si es asi, solo se debe ordenar la parte de: `cielago`..